# Include topic name in list of improvements

Tags: feature-request, documentation

In the list of improvements within a tag (e.g. [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23)), can we show the title of the topic when the improvement is referring to an example? Currently it shows the title of the example, which can be confusing. See the screenshot below, it would be nice if the second entry said it was for *Reactive Extensions* and the last one is for *Unsafe code in .NET*.

[image: 1]]